# Android ListView onTouchEvent doesn't give ACTION_DOWN

Tags: android, android-listview, touch

In order to have list reordering functionality I turned to [this implementation](http://ericharlow.blogspot.de/2010/10/experience-android-drag-and-drop-list.html?showComment=1332171356419#c7022544393803712338).

My problem is that when I try to drag an item in my ListView, I don't get the ACTION_DOWN event. Instead, for a single smear down motion I get 2 ACTION_MOVE events (action=0x00000002) and a single ACTION_UP event (action=0x00000001) in this order.

I've looked at similar questions but it seems like everyone has the opposite problem, getting only ACTION_DOWN events.
Can anyone think of why this is happening?

Thanks,
Yoel

Comment: we can't help you without seeing some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I needed to add this small piece of code:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Now I get the ACTION_DOWN events in the OnTouchEvent function and it all works fine.

Comment: thank you for posting your solution. please mark your answer as the correct answer..

Comment: The posted answer by NeTeInStEiN works better for me. It is more work but I have to deal with odd behaviors in my Listview.

Answer (score 2):

I was using the same code.

My problem was also that something was consuming the event and I didn't managed to found what was it... but i managed to solve it using **onInterceptTouchEvent** to return true on the events i needed on  **onTouchEvent**.

Problem solved :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! Indeed this helped. I made both events to invoke the same function and I see some action.

Comment: I override onInterceptTouchEvent and filter the MotionEvent actions I am interested (ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_MOVE). In the method with those actions, it calls onTouchEvent and return false. If I do not filter the action events, then it calls super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev) method.